# Rails 5 - pushing to GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I was pushing normally to my repository, but I had to delete that one due to mistakes I made.

Afterwards, I made a new repository and connected it, but when I try to push my whole code to that repository, it does not get pushed since I have no changes.

> On branch final-branch
>      nothing to commit, working tree clean

If I type `git add --all` and push it all to a new branch, only `.txt` files get pushed, nothing else.

How can I push my whole code to a new repo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a new remote:

```
git remote add new-remote https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

To check if the add work fine:

```
git remote -v
```

You should see something like:

> new-remote https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
>   new-remote https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)

A then you can push to your new remote:

```
git push new-remote master
```

Comment: Great @Seinfeld